# Create div inside a div using Angular

Tags: html, angular

I am having the code inside my file which is,

```
<kendo-chat
    [messages]="feed | async"
    [user]="user"
    (sendMessage)="sendMessage($event)">
  </kendo-chat>
```

Once it is loaded in the browser, it contains this code

```
<kendo-chat>
  <div class="k-message-box">
     <input class="k-input" type="text" placeholder="Type a message..." />
     <button class="k-button-send k-button k-flat"></button>
  </div>
</kendo-chat>
```

I cant manually edit what's inside the `<kendo-chat>`. I want to add a div element inside it and this is my expected result.

```
<kendo-chat>
  <div class="k-message-box">
     //ADDED DIV
     <div>
       <i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i>
     </div>
     //ADDED DIV
     <input class="k-input" type="text" placeholder="Type a message..."/>
     <button class="k-button-send k-button k-flat"></button>
  </div>
</kendo-chat>
```

Can someone help me on how to do that using Angular 8. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in which case you want to add the div? is there any particular reason why `*ngIf` would not be ok ?

Comment: because the first div is already loaded inside a kendo component, and there is no way to edit it manually

Answer (score 2):

So, you can't use `*ngIf` because this is an external component.

Then you can use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) inside `ngAfterViewInit` or after in the lifecycle.

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}

ngOnInit() {
  const div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
  const text = this.renderer.createText('Hello world!');

  this.renderer.appendChild(div, text);
  this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, div);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put those explicitly, just add and hide by *ngIf and show when you need it.

Comment: The first div is inside a kendo component in which you can't edit manually or adding an element inside it.

Comment: That's why I want to programmatically append the second div.

Answer (score 0):

Worse case scenario you can add it manually with simple js.

In `ngAfterViewInit` you make a `setTimeout` which will me called after angular is finished, and the html is ready and rendered, and change it with js.